# How should I use the id() function in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

I am a beginner developer in Python. I am wondering if the `id()` function can be
used for encrypt program, or is it just used to give the *element id* for that value in memory?

I just want to know how I can use this function and which
situations it is good for use. Here is an example:

```
Input : id(1025) # 1025 is a value stored in memory
Output : 140365829447504
       or
Input : id("geek") # A string literal is stored in memory
Output : 139793848214784
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id()` function just gives the identity of the Python object in memory. From the docs:

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id value.

As such this is not something that should be used for encryption.